I am not able to visualize the globe part of the Cesium JS
I am a beginner trying to learn to Cesium JS for Web GIS projects.I downloaded and installed the Cesium 1.119 library in my laptop. Now I am not able to see the basic globe part on the screen. I have attached the code and an image of the current result here.
What can I try next?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="http://localhost:8085/3d/libs/Cesium-1.119/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8085/3d/libs/Cesium-1.119/Apps/Sandcastle/Sandcastle-header.js"></script>

</head>

<style>
    @import url(http://localhost:8085/3d/libs/Cesium-1.119/Apps/Sandcastle/CesiumSandcastle.css);

    @import url(http://localhost:8085/3d/libs/Cesium-1.119/Apps/Sandcastle/templates/bucket.css);
</style>

<body>
    <div id="cesiumContainer" class="fullSize"></div>
    <div id="loadingOverlay">
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="toolbar"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer",{
                  Geocoder: false,
                  Animation: true,
                  CreditsDisplay: false,
                  Timeline: false,
                  FullscreenButton: false
                });
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>


I am not sure why you are facing this issue, you can take the official docs example and implement them in your code and it should work.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>


  <script src="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.119/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.119/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<style>

</style>

<body>
  <div id="cesiumContainer" class="fullSize"></div>
  <div id="loadingOverlay">
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="toolbar"></div>

</body>

</html>

JS Fiddle Demo

I tried with the official docs example as well. But the problem still persists.

I found a way to open the correct way to access the complete Cesium library through the same server for both Geoserver and Webserver.

Tomorrow the system should allow you to tick/check this answer, marking it as your solution.
